# Show false if field empty, function results if not

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to fix the following condition:

```
=if(AND($L$1>=F9,F9="");"exsteeded";"")
```

This will actually do, if a certain date is over the current date, the exceeded will show. but it have to return false, cause f9 (the certain date) is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Nested IFs should do fine - check for empty first, return either "false" or the results of your date-exceeded check:

```
=if(F9="","False",IF($L$1>=F9,"exeeded",""))
```

However, if L1 contains the due date, and F9 contains a date to check against the due date, you may want to reverse the comparison to be "<" or "<=" instead of ">="

```
=if(F9="","False",IF($L$1<F9,"exeeded",""))
```